# Excel Interop C# and Deployment to Production Box

Tags: excel, interop, production

I'm using the Excel Interop in C# (VS 2008) wrapped around WCF service. It works fine in my development box. However on the production server, we don't have the MS Office installed nor VS2008. What needs to be done in the production server in order to make Excel Interop work fine?  Do I package the Interop DLLs into the bin folder?  How does that work?

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can include the interop assemblies in your deployment package but you remember that those assemblies are just wrappers around unmanaged Excel libraries so you need to install Excel on the production box for this to work. And if this is a server application you probably shouldn't be using Excel interop at all as Excel is a client application not intended to be used in a heavy multithreaded environment such as an ASP.NET application.

Comment: When you say install Excel, do you mean MS-Office suite?

Comment: @JKK, that depends, if you are using only Excel interop in your application you definitely don't need to install Work or PowerPoint.